# how to change font color in echo values with background color?

Tags: php, css

how to change font color in echo values with background color.My code is

```
<tr style="background-color: 
     <?php if($rows['cars']=="1") { ?>
               #FFFF00
     <?php } else if ($rows['cars']=="2") { ?>
               #00CC99
     <?php }  else if ( $rows['cars']=="3" ) { ?>
               #F00
     <?php } ?> ">
```

Comment: I need font color to change

Comment: You should use `color:` instead of `background-color:` if you want to change the font color rather than the background color

Comment: @NolanKnill I would like to keep both as it labels three different output

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $color = '';
    switch($rows['cars']){
       case "1": $color="#FFFF00";break;
       case "2": $color="#00CC99";break;
       case "3": $color="#F00";break;
    }
?>

 <tr  style="color:<?php echo $color;?>;" >
```

Comment: I need font color to change

Comment: <tr  style="color:<?php echo $color;?>;" >

Comment: I would like to keep both as it labels three different output

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr  style="background-color:<?php if($rows['cars']=="1")
{ echo "#FFFF00"; } else if ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your code up & it all falls into place. Also, don’t try to shove all the PHP logic into `<?php`/`?>` tags embedded in HTML. Use PHP to manage the logic & echo the HTML instead.

```
<?php

if ($rows['cars']=="1") {
  $bgcolor = '#FFFF00';
}
else if($rows['cars']=="2") {
  $bgcolor = '#00CC99';
}
else if ($rows['cars']=="3") {
  $bgcolor = '#F00';
}
echo sprintf('<tr style="background-color: %s">', $bgcolor);

?>
```

Or perhaps use an array:

```
<?php

$bgcolor_array = array();
$bgcolor_array[1] = '#FFFF00';
$bgcolor_array[2] = '#00CC99';
$bgcolor_array[3] = '#F00';

$bgcolor = array_key_exists($rows['cars'], $bgcolor_array) ? $bgcolor_array[$rows['cars']];
echo sprintf('<tr style="background-color: %s">', $bgcolor);

?>
```

Comment: I would like to keep both as it labels three different output